# Как в цикле вывести поочередно элементы списка бесконечное количество раз?

Tags: python, while

Мне нужно чтобы через каждые 10 минут программа выводила мне один элемент из списка поочередно, но потом, когда программа дойдет до конца списка, начала опять перечислять элементы по новой.

Как мне это сделать?

Примерный код:

```
import time
import schedule
spisok = [1,2,3]

while True:
    def idi():
        for i in spisok:
            print(i)

    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(idi)
    
    while True:    
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: воспользуйтесь [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Comment: @БогданМусихин Решение действительно не помогло? Я проверил, всё работает.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
import time
import schedule
from itertools import cycle

spisok = [1,2,3]

iterator = cycle(spisok)

while True:
    def idi(iterator=iterator):
        print(next(iterator))

    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(idi)
```

---

Пример работы `cycle`:

```
In [71]: iterator = cycle(spisok)

In [72]: [next(iterator) for _ in range(17)]
Out[72]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```